# How to return data in a standard way?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to figure out how to return my data in a standard way. What I mean by this is when I return json or xml it would be nice to have one format for everything(success and errors).

Say I have the following json result.

```
{
  "person": {
    "id": 12345,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "phones": {
      "home": "800-123-4567",
      "work": "888-555-0000",
      "cell": "877-123-1234"
    },
    "email": [
      "jd@example.com",
      "jd@example.org"
    ],
    "dateOfBirth": "1980-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "registered": true,
    "emergencyContacts": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "phone": "",
        "email": "",
        "relationship": "spouse|parent|child|other"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is all fine but now what happens if there is a validation error

I could use the built in method CreateErrorResponse

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "item": [
      "Required property 'Name' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 14."
    ],
    "item.Name": [
      "The Name field is required."
    ],
    "item.Price": [
      "The field Price must be between 0 and 999."
    ]
  }
}
```

*Yes I know the data does not make sense and is different but data is irrelevant only the structure is.

Now what happens if I have an error and in this case it is has a custom error code.

I could return something like this(using HttpError)

```
{
  "Message": "My custom error message",
  "CustomErrorCode": 37
}
```

Now you can see I have 3 different formats of json coming back. Now on the client I would have to do this

1. Check HttpStatusCode

   - If 200 then in this case parse json using format of Person.
   - If 400 then could be a validation error or server error.
   - If Customer error is found then use that format otherwise use modlestate.

I been working with foursquare and it seems like they always return the same format back to the user but I have no clue how to get the same sort of thing when I do it.

```
  {
          "meta": {
            "code": 200,
             ...errorType and errorDetail...
          },
          "notifications": {
             ...notifications...
          },
          "response": {
             ...results...
          }
        }
```

I would like to do something similar to it like

would be an ok request.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
         "ModelState": {}
    },
    "response": {
        "person": {
            "id": 12345,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "phones": {
                "home": "800-123-4567",
                "work": "888-555-0000",
                "cell": "877-123-1234"
            },
            "email": [
                "jd@example.com",
                "jd@example.org"
            ],
            "dateOfBirth": "1980-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
            "registered": true,
            "emergencyContacts": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "phone": "",
                    "email": "",
                    "relationship": "spouse|parent|child|other"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

server error would look like this

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "this is a server error",
        "ModelState": {}
    },
    "response": {}
}
```

validation would look like this

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "validation errors",
        "Message": "The request is invalid.",
        "ModelState": {
            "item": [
                "Required property 'Name' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 14."
            ],
            "item.Name": [
                "The Name field is required."
            ],
            "item.Price": [
                "The field Price must be between 0 and 999."
            ]
        }
    },
    "response": {}
}
```

but like I said not sure how to do something like this and not 100% certain this is the best way still. At least it should be one format then?

**Edit**
@Erik Philips

When I was doing just asp.net mvc projects I would do something like this.

```
public readonly IValidation validation;

public PersonService(IValidation validation)
{
    this.validation = validation;
}

public Person GetPerson(int id)
{

    try
    {
       return FindPerson(id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //log real error with elmah
        validation.addError("internal", "Something went wrong");
    }
}


public class PersonController
{
     public readonly IPersonService personService;
     public PersonController(IPersonService personService)
     {
       this.personService = personService;
     }

    public ActionResult GetPerson(int id)
    {
        personService.GetPerson(id);

        if(personService.Validation.IsValid)
        {
          // do something
        }
        else
        { 
          // do something else
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

I like how you set it up but I would like to keep it sort of that way. I don't think I can use a interface but I was thinking of something like this

```
public PersonService()
{

}

public ResponseResult<Person> GetPerson(int id)
{
    var result = ResponseResult<Person>();
    try
    {
       return FindPerson(id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       result.Errorcode = 200;
       result.Msg = "Failed";
    }
}


public class PersonController
{
     public readonly IPersonService personService;
     public PersonController(IPersonService personService)
     {
       this.personService = personService;
     }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetPerson(int id)
    {
       var result = personService.GetPerson(id);
       if(result.isValid)
       {
          Request.CreateResponse<ResponseResult<Person>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
       }

         Request.CreateResponse<ResponseResult<Person>>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this API going to be consumed internally (inside the company) or externally (by 3rd parties)?

Comment: Only internally for my own projects but I was thinking whatever way is made could be used for any webapi project(internal or 3rd parties).

Comment: Do you also want this API to be consumed by Javascript (jQuery etc)?

Comment: I don't see it being consumed by web since I need a bar code scanner and planning to write native apps instead of say phonegap what I would use javascript then. However as this is a web api I am really trying to learn how to make it so anything can use it. I would still use CreateResponse or CreateErrorResponse and wrap it around another code so jquery should be able to look at that as well to see if it was "ok" or "bad" or "internal error".

Comment: I really am trying to find the best practice way of returning the data. I don't see having to always check 3 formats of json to figure out what just came from the server is the best way.

Comment: You don't *have* to use `CreateErrorMessage()`. Set up an [exception filter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling#exception_filters) on your API, and have it produce a custom formatted response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a large question as it's the design to send data which has multiple parts, but I believe this is a fairly easy, small and elegant solution.

This isn't exactly what I use, but it a good example:

First lets build out a model that represents what all responses need, or can be used when no result data is required:

```
public class ResponseResult
{
    public ResponseResult()
    {
    }

    public ResponseResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        this.ModelState = new ModelStateResult (modelState);
    }

    // Is this request valid, in the context of the actual request
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    // Serialized Model state if needed
    public ModelStateResult ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

Next, there is probably a large set of different types of results to return, and here Generics come in Handy:

```
public class ResponseResult<T> : ResponseResult
{
    public ResponseResult() : base()
    {
    }

    public ResponseResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        : base(modelState)
    {
    }

    public ResponseResult(T Data, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        : base (modelState)
    {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

So now if you need to return a `Person` you can return:

```
var result = ResponseResult<Person>();

result.Data = person;

//serialize result and send to client.
```

My APIs can be consumed by Javascript so I change the Http Status code, and give examples on how to use jQuery to redirect and consume the data.

```
request = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    processResponseResult(data);
  }
  complete: function(e, xhr, settings)
  {
    if(e.status === 401)
    {
      // login to 
    }
    // else if (e.status == ) 
    else
    {
      // unknown status code
    }
)};
```

You may want to extend the result to be consumed by a client that may not even be using http (WCF) in the future:

```
public class ResponseResult
{
   ....
   ....
   public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

or Take it a step further:

```
public class ResponseErrorBase
{
   public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseResult
{
   ....
   ....
   public ResponseErrorBase Error { get; set; }
}
```

so you could add more error types/information in the future.

**Update Per Comments**

*Comment 1: If you have a collection of people then you have..*

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
var result = new ResponseResult<List<Person>>();
result.Data = persons;
```

*Comment 2: There are 2 classes..*

If your API had a call a `FileExists(fileName)` then you don't really have to return an object, just that the call succeeded.

```
var result = new ResponseResult();
result.IsValid = FileExists(fileName);
```

If your API wanted to return the ID of a new `Person` you could return the new ID.

```
var result = new ResponseResult<Guid?>();
result.IsValid = CreatePerson(personInfo);
if (result.IsValid)
{
  result.Data = personInfo.ID;
}
```

Or you could return back new a successful `Person` object, or null if not successful.

```
var result = new ResponseResult<Person>();
result.IsValid = CreatePerson(personInfo);
if (result.IsValid)
{
  result.Data = Person;
}
```

**Update Per Comments**

What I would recommend is what I wrote earlier and include the `ResponseErrorBase` in the ResponseResult:

```
public class ResponseResult
{
  public ResponseResult()
  {
  }

  public ResponseResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
  {
    this.ModelState = new ModelStateResult (modelState);
  }

  public bool IsValid { get; set; }
  public ModelStateResult ModelState { get; set; }
  public ResponseErrorBase Error { get; set; }
}
```

Then derive your error from the base to something specific:

```
// this isn't abstract because you may want to just return
// non-specific error messages
public class ResponseErrorBase
{
  public int Code { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class InternalResponseError : ResponseErrorBase
{
  // A Property that is specific to this error but
  // not for all Errors
  public int InternalErrorLogID { get; set; }
}
```

Then return it (example for returning the value, you'll want more logic):

```
var result = new ResponseResult<Person>();

try
{
  result.Data = db.FindPerson(id);
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
  var error = ResponseErrorBase();
  error.Code = 415;
  error.Message = "Sql Exception";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  var error = InternalResponseError();
  error.InternalErrorLogID  = Log.WriteException(ex);
  error.Code = 500;
  error.Message = "Internal Error";
}

// MVC might look like:
return this.Json(result);
```

Comment: I have not gone completely through the code but what happens if you are returning a collection of "People" would anything changet hat you have?

Comment: Your ResponseResult do you have 2 classes or it or just one? If 2 how did you get the same name for each one?

Comment: Updated per your comments.

Comment: I have updated my original post. I wondering if the way I am thinking is a good way to do it.

Comment: Updated per your comments.  You can certainly do it the way you posted in your question as well.

Comment: Cool then I think I am going to try that out. I guess the only thing that I not 100% sure how to do is this case. In a past project I saved a bunch of records all at once. Some of the records could be successful or failed(many reasons already in db for instance). So if 50 inserts where done I could have 50 success or 25 successes and 25 failures. Not sure if I would have to make the ResponseErrorBase a collection as well for a case like this.

Comment: This is a tough question.  I would recommend creating a `BatchInsertError` that contained the list of failed inserts.

Comment: What do you mean would that be a separate property on top of the ResponseErrorBase? How about success messages they are needed as well or do you let the client handle that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28581/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-chobo2)